# How do I change 2 states properly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 spans and state for them:

```
const Sorter = () => {
  const [sorterTabs, setSorterTabs] = useState([
    {id:'The cheapest', isActive: false },
    {id:'The fastest', isActive: false }
  ])

  const handleSorterClick = ({ target }) => {
    const newSorterTabs = [...sorterTabs]
    newSorterTabs.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id === target.getAttribute('name')) {
        item.isActive = !item.isActive
      }
    })
    setSorterTabs(newSorterTabs)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {sorterTabs.map((item) => 
        <SorterSpan 
          key={item.id}
          onClick={handleSorterClick}
          name={item.id}
          className={item.isActive ? 'active' : ''}
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

const SorterSpan = ({name, onClick, className}) => {
  return (
    <span 
      onClick={onClick} 
      className={className}
      name={name}
    >
      {name}
    </span>
  )
}
```

I understand how I can change `isActive` property for each of span. What I need is if I click one span, and it's property `isActive` becomes true the other span `isActive` needs to become false and the same for the second span. How to do it properly in `handleSorterClick` function?

Comment: Do you consider using a toggle button? If yes, you can find the documentation here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props

Comment: You can just add a simple else condition to check to your if and return the current current state instead of returning !isActive. It's a bizarre way to loop through state and creating components though... I'd create multiple components and hold their states separately unless you have a strong reason not do

Comment: @Hemant Jain, no, don't need

Comment: @Ugur Yilmaz, hm, seems that construction doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better, cleaner and faster approach for what you're trying to do is this:

```
const Sorter = () => {
  const sorterTabs = [{ id: "The cheapest" }, { id: "The fastest" }];
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  const handleSorterClick = ({ target }) => {
    setSelected(target.name);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {sorterTabs.map((item) => (
        <SorterSpan
          key={item.id}
          onClick={handleSorterClick}
          name={item.id}
          className={selected === item.id ? "active" : ""}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const SorterSpan = ({ name, onClick, className }) => {
  return (
    <span onClick={onClick} className={className} name={name}>
      {name}
    </span>
  );
};
```

in this way if you want to grow your spans and wanted to use `n span` instead of `2` you only need to add them to your `sorterTabs` variable

Comment: @rgdzv My bad, didn't read that part of your question. you only have two span?right?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to create a state for each span, map the spans, and control things that way. This way if your app grows you only have to create a new state for each span.... or even use the useContext hook or redux, but that does not apply here. This would be my logic.